# Setting a validation rule on a custom object date

Tags: validation

Hi I`m trying to implement a validation rule in a custom object with reference to another custom object. Both are date-objects.

I tried the following Code. The syntax is correct according to salesforce, but when i try to create a new custom object i get the error message "Validation Formula "test" Invalid (Invalid year for DATEVALUE function)" independent of the dates.

Can anyone helo me?

> valid_from__c < DATEVALUE('$ObjectType.Journey__c.Fields.valid_to__c')

Comment: What do you mean with 'date-objects'? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I would like to make shure that no custom object is within a time periode of another one. A specific time periode should be blocked by just one custom object. Therefor I check if any "valid_from"-dates of a new custom object are within a blocked time periode or in other words before any "valid-to"-dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, assuming `Journey__c` is your lookup field API name:

`valid_from__c < Journey__r.valid_to__c`

*edited from* `valid_from__c < Journey__r.Fields.valid_to__c`

Comment: Hi I tried this one but I get a syntax error "Error: Field Journey__r does not exist. Check spelling."

Comment: Assuming Journey__c is your lookup field API name... Just update with the correct name.

Comment: Hi the API name is "Journey__c"

Comment: valid_from__c < Journey__r.valid_to__c should work